# ActiveRecord::Relation.last inconsistent results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a subscription application with Users, Orders and DeliverySchedules (and other models that make a has_many :through necessary instead of a has_many).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :deliveryschedules, :through => :orders

class Deliveryschedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :users, :through => :orders

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :deliveryschedule
```

My question is, why does

```
@allusers.each do |t|
    User.find_by_id(t.id).deliveryschedules.last.delivery_date
end
```

return something different from

```
@allusers.each do |t|
    t.deliveryschedules.last.delivery_date
end
```

My app is working, but I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here I can't track down in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal database behavior. The order of records that are returned from the database is undetermined, unless you specifically use `ORDER BY`. So it is possible that two different queries will return the rows in different order.

Comment: But what I don't understand is how these are two different queries? Also, it doesn't appear I can ORDER BY ActiveRecord::Relations - is there a straightforward way to ensure I'm getting the last ID from my deliveryschedules table?

Comment: @RubyNoob Yes - you can ensure you're getting the last id if you use `.order(:id)` on whichever relation you're getting the `.last` from.